# How to fix alignment of algorithm in latex

Tags: latex

I need to fix the alignment of this LaTeX code.

When I compile it, the output has the wrong alignment of `if`, `for`, `else` statements.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
       \caption{:The $ASP\_Tree$ algorithm}     
       \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
       \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}   
       \Input{TV database and min\_sup }
         \Output{Bla bla bla}
         \KwData{bla bla bla} 
         \Procedure{Tree}{$TV_i, min\_sup$}
        {
            \State {$[Root] \leftarrow [NULL]$} \newline
            \For {$i=1$ to $N$} {\label{forins} \newline
                {
                %\Statex \Comment {\%Comments: insert TV values into the tree based on rules}
                        \State {$Root \leftarrow TV_1$}
                        \State {$i \leftarrow i+1$} \newline                        
                        \If {TV_i \textgreater Root}
                    \State Root \gets TV_i
                        \ELSIF {TV_i\leq Root}
                    \State i\gets i+1
                        \ELSE
                              \State do something interesting
                        \ENDIF
                        }
              \EndFor   
                            }
            \EndProcedure       
            \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Hi! In this case it would be particularly useful if you posted a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've cleaned up the introduction; however, it could benefit from a clear description of what the "wrong" alignment is.

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot upload the output of this code because I dont have enough reputation.  However, I can say one problem as follows: Problem is under the if statement. statements are supposed to be seen under the if block but these are showing out side of the if block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that you're mixing notations of different packages, which are inherently incompatible. You should choose *either* [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) *or* [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (which provides `algpseudocode` and `algcompatible`), not both.

Here is an `algorithm2e` implementation of what you might be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e,amsmath}

\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output\,}
\SetKwInOut{Data}{Data}
\SetKwProg{Tree}{Tree}{}{EndTree}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{The ASP\_Tree algorithm}
  \Input{TV database and min\_sup}
  \Output{Bla bla bla}
  \Data{bla bla bla}
  \Tree{$TV_i, min\_sup$}{
    $[\text{Root}] \gets [\text{NULL}]$\;
    \For {$i = 1$ to $N$} {
      $\text{Root} \gets TV_1$\;
      $i \gets i + 1$\;
      \uIf {$TV_i > \textup{Root}$}{
        $\text{Root} \gets TV_i$\;}
      \uElseIf{$TV_i \leq \textup{Root}$}{
        $i \gets i+1$\;}
      \Else{
        do something interesting\;
      }
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Werner it does work. Thanks so much. You are right as I was mixing up algorithm/algorithm2e and algorithmic. Can you please let me know, how to print a horizontal line before and after the algorithm. Also, I would like to show the caption above the line.

Comment: @David: You might be interested in `\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}`.

Comment: Now perfectly works. Thanks a lot.